# Error when writing to Android sdcard

Tags: java, android

I am trying to open an output stream and write it into my device.

Whenever I try to open an output stream with the path I have on the sd card, I get a
`java.io.FileNotFoundException.`

But I am able to open the same file path when I try to open it with the device internal storage.
I have given the permission in manifest file to write into sd card.

Below are two file paths

In Device internal storage

```
/data/data/test.android/cache/9b77fb19-0c1a-441a-8a00-a762898a6648,workspace:/SpacesStore/c3c5f8f8-2dab-443d-8914-5dbfe499054e;1.0
```

In SD card

```
/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/test.android/cache/9b77fb19-0c1a-441a-8a00-a762898a6648,workspace:/SpacesStore/c3c5f8f8-2dab-443d-8914-5dbfe499054e;1.0
```

As you can see, everything after 'cache/' is the same.

Below is the file writing code

```
    String path = downloadedDirectory + File.separator + document.getRepositoryId() + FILENAME_SEPARATOR+ document.getId(); 
  //downloaded directoy is the directory what user selects either sd card or app internal      storage. Document repository id and document id i get from my backend.
//should not be of any issue here.

    File file= new File(path);
    randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
```

I am getting exception while trying to create the random access file.

cheers,
Saurav

Comment: post your code of file writing.

Comment: In particular, post the code where you are generating those paths.

Comment: thanks Hamid and CommonsWare ...i have updated with the code

Comment: "i have updated with the code" -- not enough code. Where is `downloadedDirectory` coming from?